# Angular2 nested components vs auxiliary routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I could use nested components or auxiliary routes to layout my Angular 2 application.

Does anyone have advice on when to use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested components are usually statically defined or added dynamically using `ViewContainerRef`, components added by the router (aux or normal outlet) are added depending on the route.

The main distinction is if you want to reflect the currently added component in the browsers URL bar. If you want this, use the router and outlets, otherwise use `ViewContainerRef` or add it statically or use `*ngIf`, `*ngSwitch`, ...